# Conda create is stuck at "solving package specifications"

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, anaconda, conda

I'm trying to create a Python 2.7 virtual environment with Anaconda so I can download some packages that are not compatible with Python 3.4. I'm working in Conda version 4.2.13.

When I type the command `conda create -n chemistry python=2.7 anaconda` the whole thing freezes at the `solving package specifications` stage.

Does anyone know what causes this or how I can go about fixing it?

Comment: Do you really need the `anaconda` package in there? Why not state explicitly the package you need to install and let Conda figure out the rest: `conda create -n chemistry <channel>::<some_pkg_py27>`

Comment: I propose we close this as a duplicate of [conda create environment not responding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66888484/conda-create-environment-not-responding). While this one is older, the user asking here has been inactive and no answer has been accepted.

Comment: Try installing mamba to your conda base, and use mamba instead of conda. It solves many "conda frozen" issues. https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/mamba

Answer (score 1):

I switched to pyenv, more lightweight and not intrusive on your environment as conda.

```
#list available python versions
pyenv install -l 
#install
pyenv install 2.7.9
#activate 2.7.9
pyenv global 2.7.9
#check version
python --version
#create virtual env
python -m venv chemistry
#activate env
./chemistry/scripts/activate
```

For package management you could investigate poetry

Answer (score 0):

Today I faced the same snag. It got fixed after updating my Anaconda Navigator.

Updating your Anaconda Navigator may fix your issue, too.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
conda create -n chemistry python=2.7
```

The initial command you use will try to install a package named `anaconda`. If you want to specify the channel when installing packages,you can add `-c <channel>`.For example:

```
conda install -c conda-forge tqdm
```

Answer (score 0):

Had same issue while I was trying to install some packages. I tried updating python then all seemed working. Try it out
conda install python

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. The solution that worked for me was to create the virtual environment with anaconda but install the packages using pip.

```
conda create -n chemistry python=2.7

pip install <required packages>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).