# conda create environment not responding

Tags: anaconda, conda, environment

I want to install python 2.7 as a conda environment.

```
conda create -n python2 python=2.7 anaconda
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment:
```

it's been running for the last 12 hours.

Comment: 12 hours... wow you are patient. When you install anaconda, that pulls in dozens (hundreds?) of extra packages. That can really prolong the installation process. Can you try creating the environment without anaconda? Specify the packages you know you need.

Comment: @jakub it worked ...thanks

Comment: @jakub how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all that is actually needed is Python 2.7 environment (not full Anaconda distribution), then [see @jakub's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66889109/570918). However, Conda is perfectly capable of creating an Anaconda distribution environment with Python 2.7, and it should not take 12+ hours to solve.

### Why so long? Channels!

The extremely long solve is almost certainly aggravated by your channel priorities. An "Anaconda" distribution should source most - if not all - of its software from the **anaconda** channel (part of **defaults** channel). However, most users eventually add **conda-forge** into their global channels and give it higher or equal priority (e.g., `channel_priority: flexible`). When this is the case, Conda will spend a bunch of time trying to satisfy the packages specified within the `anaconda` metapackage with the latest versions from **conda-forge**, and that's what tends to bog things down.

### Option 1: Avoid Mixing Anaconda and Conda Forge

If you want a faster Anaconda install, then install only from Anaconda

```bash
conda create -n anaconda27 --override-channels -c defaults python=2.7 anaconda
```

Everything in the `anaconda` metapackage was originally intended to be sourced from the **anaconda** channel, so this shouldn't be so unreasonable.

Note that if you have **conda-forge** prioritized globally, this will be an issue every time you install in this environment (so remember to override channels).

### Option 2: Mamba

Another option is [Mamba](https://mamba.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html). It's a faster (compiled) drop-in alternative to the `conda` CLI functionality. It seems to both solve faster and less prone to mutate unrelated packages when requesting changes - but that's just my anecdotal experience.

```bash
# install it in your *base* env (only need this once)
conda install -n base conda-forge::mamba

# use it like you would `conda`
mamba create -n python2 python=2.7 anaconda
```

Answer (score 2):

The `anaconda` package is a *metapackage*, meaning it tells conda to install other packages. It will install hundreds of packages, and it turns out this can stress `conda`. One typically does not need all of the packages in the `anaconda` metapackage -- it is often better to install only the packages one requires.

Try to create an environment without `anaconda` and instead specify only the packages you need.

```
conda create -n python2 python=2.7
```